# Timeout waiting for modules to be invalidated

Tags: react-native

I've a react-native application which was using v0.43, a few days ago , i've decided to upgrade it to v0.48, and faced a lot of issues but found a solutions for them, and now my application starts and only loading screen it give me this error

> Timeout waiting for modules to be invalidated

i've searched for it, but didn't found a solution ? any suggestions ?

Comment: I never saw this message before, neither could find anything related to it. It's on both android and ios? Have you tried to delete your node_modules and npm install? Also try closing your packager and run your app again. Is there any third party lib that relies on a specific React Native version? Sorry for not coming with a working solution.

Comment: I had same error. "Turn it off and turn on again" helped in my case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove all { display: 'none' } from style

```
EDIT: The answer was for an old version of react-native (0.43) and won't work for new versions.
```

Comment: This is crazy but this is the answer

Answer (score 41):

This has the exact problem's [solutions](https://garbagevalue.com/blog/timeout-waiting-for-modules-to-be-invalidated).

My wifi was off on my iPhone. I just turned on my wifi and connected to the same network as my laptop, fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Every other week I return to this thread and realize that I am dumb :D

Answer (score 11):

Saw this issue as well.  The problem was that my iPhone's wifi was on a different network than my laptop.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem too. In my case, I got it only when I press Reload from the device shake menu. I got it solved by opening a hot spot from my phone and connecting my laptop to that. Apparently, the 2 devices need to be able to communicate via a wifi connection even when the device is connected using the USB cable.

Comment: When I ran into this issue, my computer couldn't connect to my phone's hotspot either. After restarting my phone, I could connect to the hotspot again, and the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, it was caused by rendering non-english text with special characters, like `جمال`.

Removing the `letterSpacing` style property fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same issue recently and in my case was that I was working with android emulator and ios emulator on the same computer and using the same `react-native` server, what I did to fix it was to kill the server and reload in ios without reloading android and it fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours trying to solve this issue, what worked in the end was disabling my computer firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when solving issues related to the PickeriOS, I just uninstalled the app from the simulator and restarted the simulator and build again.

Answer (score 0):

I was already connected to same wifi on both the device, I disconnected wifi on both Devices and reconnected again, this did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

As an additional error source: Check your **developer settings**. I did some experiments with the **Network Link Conditioner** to simulate a bad connection. This also impacts your connection to Metro and can cause the timeout. Turning it off (and only turn it on once the app is loaded) fixed the issue for me.

Iphone Settings => Developer Settings => Network Link Conditioner